# Why did Lando Calrissian know Darth Vader was after Luke Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

When Leia, Chewbacca, and Han confront Lando about them being tortured, Lando says that Vader is not even interested in them. He's after somebody named Skywalker.

> Leia: Why are they doing this?
>
> Han: They never even asked me any questions.
>
> Lando enters with guards.
>
> Chewbacca growls.
>
> Leia: Lando.
>
> Chewbacca growls even louder and angrier, directed at Lando.
>
> Han: Get out of here, Lan ...
>
> Lando: Shut up and listen! Now Vader's agreed to turn Leia and Chewy over to me.
>
> Han: Over to you.
>
> Lando: They'll have to stay here, but at least they'll be safe.
>
> Leia: What about Han?
>
> Lando: Vader's giving him to the bounty hunter.
>
> Leia: Vader wants us all de ...
>
> Lando: **He doesn't want you at all. He's after somebody called ... uh ... Skywalker.**
>
> Han: Luke?

**How did Lando know Vader wanted Luke?**

Did Vader let that slip? Did Lando get that knowledge from other sources? It's not like anybody else with Vader (e.g. - stormtroopers) know about Vader's quest for Luke.

Is this mentioned in the novelization?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shortly after leaving the torture chamber, Vader speaks to Boba Fett and mentions "Skywalker" by name. Lando is present.

> **Vader:** *You may take Captain Solo to Jabba the Hutt **after I have Skywalker***

---

This conversation goes slightly differently in the original novelisation

> *Outside the torture chamber, Boba Fett waited for Lord Vader with Lando Calrissian and the administrator’s aide.*
>
> *With obvious disdain, Vader turned to Fett. “Bounty hunter,” Vader
>   addressed the man in the black-marked silver helmet, **“if you are
>   waiting for your reward, you will wait until I have Skywalker.”***
>
> *The self-assured Boba Fett appeared unruffled by this news. “I am in
>   no hurry, Lord Vader. My concern is that Captain Solo not be damaged.
>   The reward from Jabba the Hutt is double if he’s alive.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_V:_The_Empire_Strikes_Back_(novel))</sup></sub>

This scene is replicated in the new (canon) junior novelisation, but again the dialogue is slightly different.

> *Lando is waiting outside the door when Vader leaves the room.
>   “You said you wouldn’t hurt him!”*
>
> *Vader sweeps by the old cardsharp to where Boba Fett, the bounty hunter, is waiting.*
>
> ***“Once I have Skywalker,” Vader intones, his voice a gentle tapping on the galaxy’s largest, deepest gong, “you may take him to Jabba the Hutt.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Empire Strikes Back: So You Want to Be a Jedi?](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F)</sup></sub>